# Codeigniter - Error While Passing Variables From Container to View

Tags: forms, codeigniter, templates, codeigniter-3

Hi I want to Pass input elements values while clicking button using post method and pass values to next view using CI. When submitting the button with values in input elements and redirecting it works well. But When I'm refreshing after redirecting the page the values of input elements are lost and shows blank page/the page i display when the value becomes null.

**1st View**

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>Mapcontrol/display_garage_by_location" method="post">
                     <div class="section_1">
                         <select id="cmbcity" name="cmbcity" class="frm-field required">
                            <option value="null">Select Your City</option>
                            <option value="1">fghfghfghf</option>
                            <option value="2">fghfghfgh</option>
                            <option value="3">fghfgh</option>         
                            <option value="4">ffffffff</option>
                            <option value="5">hhhh</option>
                            <option value="6">dddd</option>
                            <option value="7">treee</option>
                            <option value="8">kiu</option>
                         </select>
                      </div>                    

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-3 dropdown-button">                      
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPlaces" placeholder="Enter a location" />     
                        <input type="hidden" id="city2" name="city2" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="cityLat" name="cityLat" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="cityLng" name="cityLng" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 dropdown-button">                    
                         <div class="section_1">
                         <select id="cmbvehicletype" name="cmbvehicletype" class="frm-field required">
                            <option value="null">Type</option>
                            <option value="cr">dd</option>         
                            <option value="mb">ghjghjd</option>
                            <option value="tk">ghjghj</option>
                            <option value="ar">hgjghj</option>
                            <option value="bi">gggh</option>
                            <option value="ov">gg</option>
                         </select>
                      </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 dropdown-button">
                      <div class="section_1">
                         <select id="cmbservice" name="cmbservice" class="frm-field required">
                            <option value="null">Select</option>
                            <option value="vr">vr</option>         
                            <option value="oc">oc</option>
                            <option value="br">br</option>
                            <option value="vs">vc</option>
                            <option value="sp">cc</option>
                            <option value="os">cd</option>
                         </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-2 submit_button"> 
 <input type="submit" id="searchindex" value="SEARCH"/>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function display_garage_by_location()
    {
        // Loading Library
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        //Initialize our map. Here you can also pass in additional parameters for customising the map
        $this->googlemaps->initialize();
        // Create the map. This will return the Javascript to be included in our pages <head></head> section and the HTML code to be 
       // placed where we want the map to appear.
       $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
       // Load our view, passing the map data that has just been created
       //$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
             $data['locationvalue']=$this->input->post('city2');
             $data['latvalue']=$this->input->post('cityLat');
             $data['longvalue']=$this->input->post('cityLng');
             $data['vehicleid']=$this->input->post('cmbvehicletype');
             $data['serviceid']=$this->input->post('cmbservice');
             $this->garage_location_markers($data);
    }

    public function garage_location_markers($data)
    {
             $this->load->view('templates/_header');
             $this->load->view('content/locations-in-marker-view',$data);
             $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
    }
```

**2nd View**

// In Second View I want to display if location value is null then dispaly `no data found` else `display search results` ..

The Problem is When location is not null it displays the details but when i refresh the page again control go back to the controller and results no data found.. How to Solve this?

Comment: please add to the question what you have tried so far and what problem you are have

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

**In View**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>controllerName/FunctionName/<?php echo $id?>">View user</a>
```

**In Controller**

```
public function FunctionName($id) # determine function that receiving incoming parameter 
{
    if (empty($id)) {
        echo "Token Missed Matched";
    }
    else{

        # get data from model
        $result = $this->model_name->model_function($id);

        if(empty($result))
        {
            echo "No data found";
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('view_name');
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible while we submit the data by submit button instead of a link

Comment: dont use get. use post. its for security reason

Comment: hi thank u i am new to CI .Actually I was about do it on post but when i pass variables from controller and display results to the view the result was according to the condition that i provided... and was working fine. But  the problem is when i refresh the page it shows a blank page

Comment: You cant load two controller function at a time. `$this->garage_location_markers($data);` will not work. Save it to database and call it or inside `display_garage_by_location()` add `garage_location_markers()` views. Bcz it only run once

Comment: ok !got it ..but how can i keep the values from controller to view .If refreshing the page the values i redirecting from controller is being lost

Comment: i didn't get that. Can you explain more?

Comment: i am passing the value of  $locationvalue to the view. When i entering data it fetches the value and display the output in view. Then if i refresh the page the value becomes null..Thank u

Comment: save it to db. and redirect it to next method. and retrieve data and check. all will be solved